# Query returning only 1 row instent of all

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm Stuck on below code... Accroding to my understanding below code should display all the rows data which has been created in my database... But im getting only 1 row data in result only one product on my product page... Please help...

```
<?php
include 'core/database/connect.php';
include 'core/includes/listhead.php';
$dynamiclist = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `index` ORDER BY price1 LIMIT 2");
$hotelcount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($hotelcount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $id             = $row['index_id'];
    $pic            = $row['main_pic'];
    $country        = $row['country1'];
    $destination    = $row['destination1'];
    $price          = $row["price1"];
    $dynamiclist    = '<div class=/"offset-2/">
                        <div class="col-md-4 offset-0">
                            <div class="listitem2">
                                <a href="" data-footer="A custom footer text" data-title="A random title" data-gallery="multiimages" data-toggle="lightbox"><img src="'. $pic .'" alt=""/></a>
                                <div class="liover"></div>
                                <a class="fav-icon" href="#"></a>
                                <a class="book-icon" href="details.html"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 offset-0">
                            <div class="itemlabel3">
                                <div class="labelright">
                                    <img src="images/filter-rating-5.png" width="60" alt=""/><br/><br/><br/>
                                    <img src="images/user-rating-5.png" width="60" alt=""/><br/>
                                    <span class="size11 grey">18 Reviews</span><br/><br/>
                                    <span class="green size18"><b>'. $price .'</b></span><br/>
                                    <span class="size11 grey">Avg/Night</span><br/><br/><br/>
                                    <form action="http://demo.titanicthemes.com/travel/details.html">
                                     <button class="bookbtn mt1" type="submit">Book</button>    
                                    </form>         
                                </div>
                                <div class="labelleft2">            
                                    <b>'. $country .'</b><br/><br/><br/>
                                    <p class="grey">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec semper lectus. Suspendisse placerat enim mauris, eget lobortis nisi egestas et.
                                    Donec elementum metus et mi aliquam eleifend. Suspendisse volutpat egestas rhoncus.</p><br/>
                                    <ul class="hotelpreferences">
                                        <li class="icohp-internet"></li>
                                        <li class="icohp-air"></li>
                                        <li class="icohp-pool"></li>
                                        <li class="icohp-childcare"></li>
                                        <li class="icohp-fitness"></li>
                                        <li class="icohp-breakfast"></li>
                                        <li class="icohp-parking"></li>
                                        <li class="icohp-pets"></li>
                                        <li class="icohp-spa"></li>
                                    </ul>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="offset-2"><hr class="featurette-divider3"></div>';
    }
} else {
    $dynamiclist = 'We Do Not Have Any Hotel Listed in This City';
}
?>
<?php echo $dynamiclist ?>
<?php include 'core/includes/listfooter.php'; ?>
```

Comment: You're overwriting `$dynamiclist` every iteration

Comment: And your query contains `limit 2` which returns only 2 rows max.

Comment: Please Suggest how to avoid this error i'm new to php... Wondering if you can edit above code...

Comment: Yes you need to check the above 2 as mentioned, dont use limit if you want all data and then initialize $dynamiclist = ''; before the query loop and inside query do $dynamiclist .= 'html'

Comment: Juergen Yes... I will set the limit to 20 but according to above query i should get 2 result but i getting only one... Help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues

Your database query is limited to 2 items (although that doesn't explain the 1 item problem you have at the moment)

removing LIMIT 2 will fix this

Secondly

```
 $dynamiclist    = '<div class=/"offset-2/">
```

the "=" sign means that you set it as the content each time.

This is fine except you echo it OUTSIDE your while loop

either echo it within your while loop or change it to

```
$dynamiclist    .= '<div class=/"offset-2/">
```

notice the .= -> that Adds items to the end of the string.

Hope that helps

Comment: No Problem - hope it all goes well!

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
  $dynamiclist    = '<div class=/"offset-2/">
```

to

```
  $dynamiclist    .= '<div class=/"offset-2/">
```

If you want to load all rows, remove 'LIMIT' from your query.